# Не получается удалить Network Manager с VPS

Tags: linux, сеть, centos, centos7

Есть несколько небольших VPS от разных хостеров. Цель: установка на них nginx + php-fpm и хостинг сайтов на них.
Где-то читал, что лучше удалять сервис Network Manager на VPS в случае если он есть, т.к. он может тормозить систему. Что я и делал до сегодняшнего дня.
Сегодня хотел поднять очередной KVM VPS и при установке обнаружил на нём Network Manager, после чего привычно выполнил:

```
systemctl status NetworkManager
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl disable NetworkManager
yum remove NetworkManager
```

ОСь на VPS CentOS 7.
После перезагрузки сервер неожиданно умер. Погуглил и переинсталлив VPS, отключил опять уже по этому ману https://cpanelhosting.ru/blog/1295
Но после перезагрузки сервер всё равно умер. network.service, кстати работал:

```
[root@server2 ~]# systemctl enable network.service
network.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig network on
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
[root@server2 ~]# systemctl start network.service
[root@server2 ~]# systemctl status network.service
network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-04-26 15:53:58 EDT; 11min ago

Apr 26 15:53:57 server2 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bring up/down networking...
Apr 26 15:53:57 server2 network[721]: Bringing up loopback interface:  Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Apr 26 15:53:57 server2 network[721]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Apr 26 15:53:57 server2 network[721]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Apr 26 15:53:57 server2 network[721]: Could not load file '/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo'
Apr 26 15:53:58 server2 network[721]: [  OK  ]
Apr 26 15:53:58 server2 network[721]: Bringing up interface eth0:  [  OK  ]
Apr 26 15:53:58 server2 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Apr 26 16:05:28 server2 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Bring up/down networking.
[root@server2 ~]# reboot
```

Вопрос: стоит ли мучаться, пытаясь удалить Network Manager? На других VPS я его удалял и, вроде, не получал никаких проблем.

К слову, я также удаляю, если есть:

```
systemctl status tuned
systemctl status polkit
systemctl status rsyslog
systemctl status avahi-daemon
systemctl status postfix
systemctl status auditd
```

Был бы рад услышать мнение профессионалов по этому поводу.

Comment: Работает — не трогай ©

Comment: А вообще сначала бы надо узнать, каков вообще способ механизм подключения машины к сети. Если вдруг нужно прописывать статический IP, то становится очевидно, что сеть падает оттого, что без NetworkManager вы нигде не прописали этот самый статический IP

Comment: NM может тормозить систему?)  он почти не кушает